# Any VPS providers with IP failover?

Tags: vps, failover, ip-address

I thought keeping this list updated could be useful for others. Here are the ones I know:

- Linode: http://blog.linode.com/2007/11/12/support-for-high-availability-ip-failover/
- Mammoth Hosting: http://www.mammothvps.com.au/add-ons/ip-failover
- Rimu Hosting:  rimuhosting.com
- TekTonic: tektonic.net/virtual-servers.html
- OVH: ovh.co.uk (Their IP Failover guide: help.ovh.com/DedieMac )
- Kimsufi: www.kimsufi.co.uk
- evoRack: evorack.com (UK. Quick replies to pre-sale questions and good reputation.)
- ensCloud: www.enscloud.com/products/cloudvps/features/ (Near the bottom regarding price.  Reviews are mixed regarding support and reliability.)

Does anyone know of any others?

Answer (score 1):

[Anchor Systems](http://www.anchor.com.au/servers/) can do that; they'll also do IP failover on your dedicated systems (and anything else you'd care to mention).  Disclaimer: I used to work for them, but they certainly don't pay me anything to spruik their stuff any more.

Comment: Cool! Their blog seems very useful too.

Answer (score 0):

Zoneedit or EasyDNS offer DNS failover... works with any hosting provider

Comment: Really, *really*, *REALLY* not the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Many VPSes that don't explicitly support IP failover can be configured to do so by using a tool like `heartbeat` along with the proper reconfiguration scripts. An example is EC2 with elastic IPs.

Configuration example: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=112816